# Removing background noise from video

Tags: video, editing, camera

Does anyone have any suggestion on removing or reducing the background noise in video recordings? Whenever I use my digital camera to shoot quick videos, I get this sound (probably because the microphone is hyper sensitive and so it picks up lot of unwanted noise) in the background. I am sure there should be some way to get rid of such sounds...

Thanks

Comment: Forgot to mention, I am looking for a PC based solution.

Comment: Do you want to get rid of ALL sound, or selectively edit?

Comment: I want to delete the background noise, for example imagine you shot a video next to a waterfall and there is this constant noise (for the purposes of your video) of water in the background. I was wondering if there is some way to reduce or eliminate such background noises.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Apple's Final Cut Pro Studio](http://www.apple.com/support/finalcutstudio/) and [Soundtrack Pro](http://www.apple.com/support/soundtrackpro/). Here's a great tutorial on how to do it: [Surgical Noise removal](http://castroller.com/podcasts/MacbreakIpodVideo/1459170).

Since you're a Windows user, I can't help you as much with audio editing. Most audio programs, including [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/), include noise gates though, so you can use it for something. Unfortunately, surgical removal is relatively unique.

If you really cannot deal with that, buy [Pro Tools](http://www.avid.com/US/products/family/pro-tools). I hate it, but it has what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This is for the **PC** - I think the best program for editing audio is **[Adobe Audition](http://www.adobe.com/products/audition.html)**.

There are so many different approaches to removing unwanted noise. A few easy filters you can apply without too much trouble are the Noise Reduction Category under the **Effects Tab**. There you have:

- [Noise Reduction](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/audition/cs/using/WS58a04a822e3e5010548241038980c2c5-7f30.html#WS58a04a822e3e5010548241038980c2c5-7f26)
- [Automatic Click Remover](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/audition/cs/using/WS58a04a822e3e5010548241038980c2c5-7f30.html#WS2A65D888-93FC-4f4f-8FAA-FD968CE6DB97)
- Click/Pop Eliminator
- [Hiss Reduction](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/audition/cs/using/WS58a04a822e3e5010548241038980c2c5-7f30.html#WS58a04a822e3e5010548241038980c2c5-7f28)

Basically, you find your noise floor and or you selectively profile the noise and then apply the filter. You can preview first, in order to see what it sounds like. I believe if the *noise is -45 dB or below* then you may have a serious problem, which means it may cost more to get rid of than its worth.

If you're looking for more advanced techniques, we can show you but it takes time, the manual and some training - remember this is more of an art, than a science - Good luck!